SQL Package publish property IgnoreDefaultSchema not working
I have .dacpac and want to publish the same with SQL package CLI. However there are some unwanted tables in the .dacpac or from the source database, which I don't want to be created in the targeted database. I tried using SQLPackage property IgnoreDefaultSchema https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage-extract?view=sql-server-ver16
But doesn't matter whether I set the value to true or false still it creates the table.
Here is a powershell script
SqlPackage /Action:Publish /SourceFile:$DacpacPath /TargetServerName:$DestinationServerName /TargetDatabaseName:$DestinationDatabaseName /p:IgnoreDefaultSchema=True
Is this kind of known issue? or is there any alternate solution.
Thanks in advance.

If the parameter does not work as expected you can issue a bug report here https://github.com/microsoft/DacFx also objects and schemas can be filtered by deployment contributor https://github.com/GoEddie/DeploymentContributorFilterer

If you can be more specific about the purpose of those tables, why are they unwanted then maybe some other options will be available
